# Is NPC death permanent?

Tags: this-war-of-mine

If I kill NPCs when out scavanging, will they stay dead? If so, is this the case every time, with every location? If there are examples to the contrary of the general case, what would those be?

As an example, I assume I can kill a couple guards at the brothel and run. Then I would have only a few of them for the next scavenging run. Is that so, or will I come back to all of them once again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From one playthrough, I can have seen that it is always or almost always the case that NPC death **is** permanent. I haven't seen evidence to the contrary yet.

Answer (score 1):

I've completed multiple (10+) play-thrus and every NPC stays dead or gone, the bodies of your PC's that die will stay until looted as well.

So you after clearing you can safely send unarmed people in to pick the goodies.

I've not played enough to know if any locations have additional mini-story-arcs that may bring more NPC's to the location at a later time but I've not seen one yet.

Comment: Thats not true. Bodies of enemies disappear if you simply leave and come back another day.

Comment: Edit your entry to mention the bodies not being permanent and I'll +1.

Comment: Are you sure, as long as there is loot in them they stay AFAIK

Comment: I've had to pick off small groups of people before booking it out of a place to make sure I lived through the encounter. I don't know if this is the case in every location, but I'm sure it is in at least a few.

Comment: @ZacharyDow Some of the locations have there own scripted events that may vary what's available. The supermarket for example, when the looters are there (not the rapist soldier), if you let the looters live and leave there seems to be less stuff available (kill em all:).